# Request gets aborted

Tags: node.js, request, jira

i am using nodejs and requesting a file to download using request module .
On piping response the operation gets aborted due econnreset exception message.
Attached code

```
async function downloadAttachment(url, filename) {
  const username = 'arjunsingh@opkey.com';
  const password = 'FfGF0AE55KddipvV4n-7VYvoK8xdGFoDSFsuANd_jkHPyxTwHP_6Q3Iti1mzXMfnEOkYdpduq2izwfIQ0_YSEQigY5m4EJoSJxxVXciU-wOgnywAEYeIb0cUmaFtXLBo37HqH0ncJfXtkseRlUclonTkpG7iam26zm569prbAhmCNPkw=91594DA2';
  var auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');
  var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'encoding': null,
    'url': url,
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': auth,
    },
    timeout: 36000000,
    redirct: 'follow',
    maxBodyLength: Infinity,
    maxRedirects: 500, // default
  };
  const filePath = 'C://Users//Admin//OneDrive//Desktop//testDownload//' + filename;
  const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
  request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("error in requesting attachment " + error.message);
      console.log("error code " + error.code);
      throw error;
    }

  }).pipe(fileStream).on('finish', () => {
    console.log(`File downloaded and saved as ${filePath}`);
  }).on('error', () => {
    console.log(`error in download ` + error);
  })
}




[Error message][1]
```

Comment: after getting a file download to some mbs the request gets aborted with error code ECONNRESET

Comment: Is this your actual password? :)

Comment: no these are old ones

Comment: Just to avoid this in the future, replace you `password` with like `xxxxx-xxxxx` because security focused developers have a panic attack seeing that posted here.